# VS2005 WebSite Project problem

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, web

I have downloaded a .net source code from the Internet.

The source code has 2 projects.

First is a Windows class lib.

Second is a WeSite project whose name is [`http://localhost/WebDemoCS`].

When I run the Web Site, VS2005 searches that location and finds nothing. So the WebSite is not run.

How can I change this setting so that I can run it from VS2005's development web server.

Comment: Sounds like you want to convert a web site project to a web application project? [Give this a try](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: What piece of source code did you download? Maybe we can look at it and see what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an included solution.  Instead, make your own by:

1. Open the class library project.
2. Open the web site as a Web Site project in VS2005.  When prompted, select File System to find the web site.

It sounds like the solution you are using is opening the web site from a Local IIS store (which was the only option in VS2003).

Comment: No, actually, web sites were not an option at all in VS2003.

Comment: @John: Since web sites weren't an option in VS2003, how could this sample been developed in VS2003 as per the OP's comment on my answer? I agree that we need to see some code, or a link to the origin of the sample.

Comment: When VS2005 first came out, it didn't support web app's.  So the VS2005 project converter converts the 2003 web app to a 2005 web site with the IIS open option for the site (unless it's been changed since I haven't used it in a while) .

Comment: @Jeff: that's not what I was asking at all. John said that web *sites* weren't even an option in VS2003.

Comment: John is right, web sites weren't an option in VS2003.  But when you open a VS2003 web project in VS2005, it is automatically converted to a web site since originally, that was the only option.  Plus, the only way I've seen [http://localhost/WebDemoCS] as a project name, is when you open a web site using the Local IIS option.